# Apostrophe got through filter in C#

Tags: c#, security, character-encoding, xss

I'm really sorry to do this, but this problem represents a possibly exploitable security issue on a site I work on, so I'm posting this with a new account.

We have a script that takes in user comments (all comments are in English). We have amassed approximately 3,000,000 comments in two years. I was checking the comments table for any signs of malicious behavior and this time I did a scan for the apostrophe. This should have been converted to an HTML entity (`&#39;`) in all cases, but I found 18 records (out of 3 million) in which the character survived. The thing that is really breaking my head is that in one of these 18 comments, one apostrophe actually was successfully converted -- the other survived.

This indicates to me that we have a possible XSS vulnerability.

My theory for what's going on is that a user is hitting the page on a computer system that uses a non-Western codepage and that their browser is ignoring our page's utf-8 charset specification, that his/her input is not getting converted to the server's local codepage until it hits the database (so C# is not recognizing the character as an apostrophe and thus is unable to convert it, but the database is when it tries to write it to a LATIN1 table). But that's a total guess.

Has anyone encountered this before or know what's going on?

And more importantly, does anyone know how I can test my script? Moving to `HttpUtility` will probably fix the situation, but until I know how this happened, I can't know the problem is fixed. I need to be able to test this to know our solution works.

**Edit**

Wow. Already at 20 points, so I can edit my question.

I mentioned in one of my comments that I found several characters that appear to be problematic. They include: 0x2019, 0x02bc, 0x02bb, 0x02ee, 0x055a, 0xa78c. These pass right through our filter. Unfortunately, they pass right through all HttpUtility encoding methods too. But once they get inserted into the database, they get converted either into a actual apostrophe or into a "?".

In review, I think the problem is that these characters do not, in themselves, pose a threat, so HttpUtility has no reason to convert them. In a block of Javascript they are harmless. In a block of HTML they are just character data and are harmless. And in a block of SQL they are harmless (if the database shares the same codepage). The problem for us is that because the codepage we're using in the database is different, the insertion process in the database involves converting these "unprintable" characters into either "known equivalents" (which in this case are "bad") and "unknown equivalents" (which get rendered as "?"). This totally blind-sided us and I'm a little disappointed in MS for not building more into their HttpUtility encoding functions.

I think the solution is to change the collation of the affected tables. But if anyone else has a better idea, please post below.

Comment: I'm sorry, did you say what the &#39;name' of the site was?

Comment: What is wrong with apostrophe char in database?

Comment: 18 of 3,000,000 indicates that was not an organized `XSS` attack. Just use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and leave it to ASP.NET security team (I hope they see this question)

Comment: @Rick - Exactly!! @zerkms - two reasons: It's being used ultimately to construct a JSON structure sent to users and the assumption was that if it was converted going into the DB, it would be safe to use verbatim coming out. Also, generally, I wanted it to be certain that if somehow, for whatever reason, a future developer decided to write a script that builds SQL statements from raw table data (e.g. to convert or move them) that the apostrophe would be a harmless HTML entity. It was to avoid a latent SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Xaqron -- for sure. But any number greater than zero is iron-clad proof that a concerted effort by attackers could succeed. It doesn't mean that we're in danger, but it means we know for certain we have a problem.

Comment: @Xaqron -- sorry, I forgot to mention, I just need to be able to test the HttpUtility methods to ensure they are working as expected. I trust MS to build a pretty robust guard against code injection, but I don't want to leave it to blind faith. The proof of the pudding...

Comment: I found a unicode character that does make it through. Unicode 0x02BC does pass through our filter unchanged and gets converted to 0x37 when being inserted into the LATIN1 table. I now have at least one character to test with. These other characters either were converted in C# or failed the codepage conversion and ended up as `?` in the database: 0x0027, 0x2019, 0x02BB, 0x02EE, 0x055A, and 0xA78C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your storage inside the DBMS is using a non-unicode column type whilst .net is using unicode.

You could within .net initially convert the unicode to your dbms' collation and then back to unicode to remove any unsupported characters at the application level rather than leaving that to the dbms/connector.

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Latin1") //this should be matched to the column's collation
foo = encoding.GetString (encoding.GetBytes (foo)); // couldn't see a more efficient way to do this.
```

Though as previously mentioned, ideally you would store the actual characters in the DBMS and leave the encoding to the presentation step. Of which you'd try and set up the framework in such a way you can't forget to encode string data, eg asp.net 4 uses `<%: %>`, JSON using JSON.Net rather than string concatenation, for XML XLINQ, etc.

Comment: Bang. You hit the nail on the head. That works for me. Unfortunately, we're not on .NET 4.0 yet. I am definitely looking forward to moving there though, for this reason.

Comment: I should say that your and @artbristol's point about when to do the encoding is totally valid. In this case, the answer solves the immediate problem. Later, when we're on 4.0 (and MVC) we can lighten up on the anti-user coding practices, but this gets us back to safe territory.

Answer (score 3):

You're filtering in the wrong place, IMHO. The database should contain the actual characters the user entered. You should leave the escaping of HTML to the presentation layer, which knows better how to do it.

Comment: Plus, if later you discover you need additional escaping, doing that on the output of unescaped content is simple. Escaping "partially escaped" content will fail.

Comment: I'm sort of torn here. On the one hand, I think you're clearly right that doing html formatting or protecting against XSS so early is a bad idea. On the other hand, I personally think user-submitted content is so intrinsically dangerous that it has to be permanently "defanged" as early as possible to prevent latent injection. The cost is that later I may have to do extra processing to undo the "defanging", but the benefit is that I never have to worry about even latent SQL injections involving user text that's already in the db.

Comment: Problem is, sanitizing user inputs depends on the context. Sometimes you have to strip HTML tags / javascript. Other times you're preventing SQL injection. It's very hard to get it right if only done in one central place on the DB. I can't count how many times I've entered text on a web site and it's come back double escaped, because someone was confused about how many unescapings needed to be done and just put in some extra 'just to be sure'.

Comment: you're completely right. Whenever I'm testing a site, I always log in as "Patty O'Brien" and I swear 50% of the time, after a few saves, I've been renamed "Patty O\\\\\\\\'Brien". And I know that there are times when mangling user input like this is going to cause heinous problems (like, what would happen in a user's discussion about SQL injection or HTML encoding problems). But that's how great my fear is of the user.

Answer (score 0):

While its always good to try and filter user content, assuming you can reliably and safely 'catch them all' isn't a reality.

Always assume the user data in your database is broken, hacked, contains pure HTML or other browser specific codes you just don't know about and instead make sure the output of all user data is safely encoded instead.

As in - HtmlEncode() all the data as its rendered to the page for a start and do it for every field the user can edit. Even basic first name fields etc, not just comment body data.

Also single quotes aren't a XSS issue its allowing tags and browser specific codes that are the issue, you can display as many single quotes as you like without a problem completetly unencoded and you can't form a XSS attack with that. You can easily do a XSS attack using tags without any single quotes (or even double quotes) however. I think you are possibly confusing SQL Injection issues (single quotes in a SQL string) with XSS issues

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm pretty religious in treating user-generated content as tainted, so I think we're good there. And unfortunately, the way this text is used actually is an XSS issue (or could be if a user could figure out how to get similar filtered characters inside the DB). For me, the basic problem is that a character got through our filter and I don't know how it did it and I don't know how to reproduce it (and so I can't test to see if our fix is working or not).

Comment: Unicode single quotes do not match a single quote so that's most likely how it got through, there is also the word based forward and reverse ones. Either way perhaps this is the kind of thing you are after? http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Comment: Other than that i think the only way to feel 100% safe is to write your own encoding function, HtmlEncode doesn't encode everything esp a lot of Unicode characters - they aren't big and don't take up too much CPU. You can white list a-z0-9 spaces and a few basic characters !@#$~ etc and encode everything else religiously! then it wont matter if its Unicode or not, any code page at all will be safe.